# Interface and concrete class naming convention in Laravel

Tags: class, oop, laravel, interface, laravel-5.1

I have an interface and a concrete class. (Item and ItemInterface.)

I am trying to avoid the "Interface" suffix but I do not know how to rename the concrete class.

For a repository I can rename them into ItemRepository (interface) and EloquentItemRepository (concrete class) but how should I proceed in other cases?

For example a Laravel package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interface naming in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541912/interface-naming-in-java)

Comment: the linked question is for Java, however the naming still applies (I suggest you read both the question and the two top answers there)